# How do I send a header for json web token to the server

Tags: node.js, jwt

I am learning to use json-web-tokens.

I got the key point that we authenticate it on the server side by getting it in the request headers.

The below mentioned lines parse the request and verify the header.

[image]

**But how do we send it in the request header in the first place.**

on MDN, [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Setting_HTTP_request_headers) link suggests using something like `httpChannel` .. but it sounds very uncommon. what is the common way of doing this?

**More Information on what I don't understand**

Excerpts from another( [this](https://coderwall.com/p/8wrxfw/goodbye-php-sessions-hello-json-web-tokens) ) tutorial :

The JWT PHP class makes this easy to do. For example, to create a token after the client successfully logs in, the following code could be used:

```
$token = array();
$token['id'] = $id;
echo JWT::encode($token, 'secret_server_key');
```

(*Now It does not mention at all about the following missing steps*)

> [ Then on client side we get the token in this way..
>
> [ ...................................// I need this which is not
>   mentioned in this tutorial
>
> [ And then we send this token to the server in this way [
>   .................................. // This too is not mentioned..

(*The tutorial directly continues with following lines.. the above lines are missing.* )

And then on later API calls the token can be retrieved and verified by this code:

```
$token = JWT::decode($_POST['token'], 'secret_server_key');
echo $token->id;
```

If the token has been tampered with then $token will be empty there will not be an id available. The JWT class makes sure that invalid data is never made available. If the token is tampered with, it will be unusable. Pretty simple stuff!
**I do understand this pretty simple stuff, However, don't understand the missing steps. **

Answer (score 0):

My solution is in JavaScript but here it is. Maybe it will help?

1.But how do we send it in the request header in the first place

```
fetch(`/secret/${uid}`, {
    method: "get",
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${getToken()}`
    }
  });
```

2.Then on client-side we get the token in this way"

If the token is saved in the local-storage we get it by this.

```
function getToken() {
  return localStorage.getItem("jwt-token");
}
```